# Memory leak due to return statement in `puts "Hello World"` method

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, emscripten

Trying to port Ruby 1.8.7 to emscripten, I have an infinite loop that does some things with ruby, using the C API, by `rb_eval_string`. Now, if I do just a `puts "Hello World"` in the loop, there is no leak. Next, if I call `my_func_one` from the main loop, there is still no memory leak, but for `my_func_two`, memory usage keeps increasing continuously. These functions are defined as

```
def my_func_one
    puts "Hello World"
end

def my_func_two
    puts "Hello World"
    return
end
```

Is this a  bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: My C code is on the lines of

```
void main_update_loop() {
    rb_eval_string("my_func_one");
}
```

where the main loop is set with `emscripten_set_main_loop(main_update_loop, 0, 1);`. I'm measuring memory usage with `memoryprofiler.js`

Comment: Can you provide a full example, including your use of `rb_eval_string`? How are you measuring the memory leak? And (sorry if this is an annoying question, but I feel obliged to check): Are you using ruby 1.8.7 for good reason, rather than a modern version?

Comment: @TomLord, updated the question. I'm using 1.8.7 primarily because it doesn't use `pthread` and the fact that the API used by the ruby code I'm going to run is based on 1.8

Comment: That's an interesting project, but porting 1.8.7 is only going to be useful from an academic perspective. Would porting JRuby be easier or better? What about Rubinius? You could also write simple stubs for the pthread functions to make them do almost nothing other than the basics.

Comment: This code may accumulate memory until the garbage collector is run. You may need to trigger that manually periodically if you're doing something really odd with Ruby, which is probably the case here.

Comment: @tadman I am calling the garbage collector manually, to no effect. Right now, I'm guessing that this has to do with the fact that *everything* related to memory works differently under emscripten, so this is just a chance that it reflects here ...